# Convert and order time in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, time, timedelta

I am trying to order `timestamps` in a `pandas` `df`. The times begin around `08:00:00 am` and finish around `3:00:00 am`. I'd like to add 24hrs to times after midnight. So times read `08:00:00` to `27:00:00 am`. The problem is the times aren't ordered.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({           
    'time' : ['08:00:00 am','12:00:00 pm','16:00:00 pm','20:00:00 pm','2:00:00 am','13:00:00 pm','3:00:00 am'], 
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

If I try order the times via

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])
df = df.sort_values(by='time',ascending=True)
```

Out:

```
 time
4 02:00:00
6 03:00:00
0 08:00:00
1 12:00:00
5 13:00:00
2 16:00:00
3 20:00:00
```

Whereas I'm hoping the output is:

```
       time
0  08:00:00
1  12:00:00
2  13:00:00
3  16:00:00
4  20:00:00
5  26:00:00
6  27:00:00
```

I'm not sure if this can be done though. Specifically, if I can differentiate between `8:00:00 am` and the times after midnight `(1am-3am)`.

Comment: A simple way is to add the `date` part (using datetime) to the time values, and make the time values "larger" than "24:00:00" associated with next day. Which date seems to be irrelevant in your case.

Comment: Thanks @nanoix9, Brad Solomon. Times will never go past 3am-4am. Could I just apply it to anything within those times. Therefore, eliminating times from 8am-12am.

Comment: @nanoix9. I would technically consider everything from the dataset as 'one date'. Even though it spans across two. But I could easily replace this.

Comment: @PeterJames123 I got a better idea if times never go beyond 4am. Why not just subtract all times by 4 hours?(but remember to add 24 hours first for times between 3am-4am). By this all times will be in range of 0 ~ 24, and also as "one date". You can easily add them back.

Comment: I'm aligning the timestamps with another dataset so they would have to be 0-27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a day offset for times after midnight and before when a new "day" is supposed to begin (pick some time after 3 am & before 7 am) & then sort values

```
cutoff, day = pd.to_timedelta(['3.5H', '24H'])
df.time.apply(lambda x: x if x > cutoff else x + day).sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)

# Out:
0   0 days 08:00:00
1   0 days 12:00:00
2   0 days 13:00:00
3   0 days 16:00:00
4   0 days 20:00:00
5   1 days 02:00:00
6   1 days 03:00:00
```

The last two values are numerically equal to 26 hours & 27 hours, just displayed differently.

If you *need* them in `HH:MM:SS` format, use string-formatting with the appropriate timedelta components

Ex:

```
x = df.time.apply(lambda x: x if x > cutoff else x + day).sort_values().reset_index(drop=True).dt.components

x.apply(lambda x: '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(x.days*24+x.hours, x.minutes, x.seconds), axis=1)

#Out:
0    08:00:00
1    12:00:00
2    13:00:00
3    16:00:00
4    20:00:00
5    26:00:00
6    27:00:00
dtype: object
```